# Mongoose Connects, queries but won't return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the following:

mongodb 7.0 in a vm (ubuntu no container)
nodejs 18+
mongoose 7.5.0
kubernetes 1.28.3

When I run the application in a kubernetes container, the application is able to connect and query the db, which is external to k8s, but it returns an empty set in every query in ever app in the cluster.

Here is the connection code which is identical to all applications.

```
// -------  Start Mongo connection ---------------------------
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.set("bufferCommands", true);
let result = true;

const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  autoIndex: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Keep trying to send operations for 5 seconds
  family: 4, // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6.
};
mongoose.set("debug", true);

const mongo_url = `${process.env.MONGO_connectionType}://${process.env.MONGO_url}/${process.env.MONGO_dbname}?replicaSet=${process.env.MONGO_replicaSet}&readPreference=${process.env.MONGO_readPreference}`;

mongoose.connect(mongo_url, options).catch((e) => {
  errorLog("Index", "app-listen", `Mongoose failed to connect to DO with error ${e.message}`, false, "error");
  result = false;
});

mongoose.connection.once("open", () => console.log(`Connected to Mongoose on DO using ${process.env.MONGO_dbName}`));
// listen for errors after the initial connection.
mongoose.connection.on("error", (error) => {
  console.error(error);
  if (error.name === "MongooseServerSelectionError") {
    console.log(error.reason.servers);
  }
  result = false;
});
mongoose.connection.on("disconnect", (error) => {
  console.error(error);
  result = false;
});
// --------------- End Mongoose Connection -------------------
```

Here is the console output of the connection and queries

```
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --trace-warnings index.js`
mainsite_server has started on port 8080
{"level":"info","message":"{\"file\":\"Index\",\"method\":\"app-listen\",\"message\":\"mainsite_server has started on porttt 8080\",\"podname\":\"mainsite-server-845cf9f56b-2hwg7\"}"}
Connected to Mongoose on DO using db_dev
Mongoose: users.createIndex({ uuid: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
Mongoose: users.createIndex({ username: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
Mongoose: users.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
Mongoose: products.find({ available: true, type: 'active', environment: 'dev' }, { sort: { level: 1 } })
Mongoose: products.find({ available: true, type: 'active', environment: 'dev' }, { sort: { level: 1 } })
Mongoose: products.find({ available: true, type: 'active', environment: 'dev' }, { sort: { level: 1 } })
```

The code doesn't issue any errors of any kind, just returns an empty result. I have run the same code at home in vscode debug accessing the same db and everything works as expected. Yes there is data in the db to return.  I am not sure how to debug this.  Any suggestions on where to look would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of right credentials, but wrong db specified. The connection string was wrong. Mongoose can be terse with error messaging. Triple check your credentials.   Doh!